# Text sequence detection

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a program that would identify text pattern in the given input text. For instance, my text would be something like this:

```
This is a test xa .. blah blah
This is a test xd .. blah blah.. 
This is a test x3 .. blah blah..
This is a test xa .. blah blah
This is a test xd .. blah blah.. 
This is a test x3 .. blah blah..
This is a test xa .. blah blah
This is a test xd .. blah blah.. 
This is a test x3 .. blah blah..
This is a test bc .. blah blah.. 
This is a test some more useless text..
This is a test x3 .. blah blah..
This is a test some more useless text..
This is a test xa .. blah blah
This is a test some more useless text..
```

I need to find a sequence of repeating *`x'digit/text'`* on alternate lines and repeating over and over again. So, in the above case, it is `xa, xd, x3` and it repeated itself 3 times. So, in another case, it could be `x1, x2, x3, x4` repeating 5 times. Can this problem be solved using regex? If I write a Java program, how do I efficiently detect this sequence?

Comment: do you know before hand what sequence you're trying to check for repetition ? and, is there a minimum number of repetitions that you want to define for a sequence to qualify for your "repeat criteria" ?

Comment: @littlecegian yes, my sequence is character x followed by digit or another alphabet. and, yes, I think the number of repetitions is a minimum of 3.

Comment: Can x followed by a digit or letter appear more than once on a line? Is it a requirement that it’s a word of its own (or does Texas qualify as xa)? My immediate expectation is you *can* use regular expressions to detect the repeating pattern, but that you wouldn’t want to.

Answer (score 2):

It surely is.
Try starting with something like [this](http://regexr.com/3df37): `.*xa.*\n.*xd.*\n.*x3.*\n`

**Edit:**

or you could to try something like [this](http://regexr.com/3df5i): `(.*x[0-9a-z].*\n)+`.

Comment: thanks for attempting to answer it. I am not looking for a regular expression for just above text - I need a generic one that will work for any 'x' and digit/alphabet combination and for any number of repetitions

Comment: Ok, I've just improved the answer, take a look, please. I think you could just search for the token you need with a simple regex and then count the matching times via Java. Don't you? I mean, if you can provide more details about the problem, I will be able to help you better. Regex is something I really like.

Comment: Done, @ClasG. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know it’s poor stackoverflow style to develop a solution for someone who hasn’t shown an effort (you haven’t even answered my questions about the requirements). Nevertheless.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RepeatingPatternMain {

    LineParser parser = new LineParser();

    public RepeatingPatternMain(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                parser.acceptLine(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        parser.done();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            new RepeatingPatternMain(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java RepeatingPatternMain <file>");
        }
    }

}

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LineParser {

    Pattern xPat = Pattern.compile(".*x([0-9a-z]).*");
    RepeatingPatternRecognizer rpr = new RepeatingPatternRecognizer();

    public void acceptLine(String line) {
        Matcher m = xPat.matcher(line);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String charAfterX = m.group(1);
            assert charAfterX.length() == 1 : charAfterX;
            rpr.lineWithX(charAfterX.charAt(0), line);
        } else {
            rpr.lineWithoutX(line);
        }
    }

    public void done() {
        rpr.finish();
    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RepeatingPatternRecognizer {

    private static final int minRepeats = 3;

    List<LineForAnalysis> lines = new ArrayList<LineForAnalysis>();

    public void lineWithX(char charAfterX, String line) {
        lines.add(new LineForAnalysis(charAfterX, line));
    }

    static class LineForAnalysis {
        final char charAfterX;
        final String line;

        public LineForAnalysis(char charAfterX, String line) {
            this.charAfterX = charAfterX;
            this.line = line;
        }
    }

    public void lineWithoutX(String line) {
        analyzeAndClear();
    }

    public void finish() {
        analyzeAndClear();
    }

    private void analyzeAndClear() {
        if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
            int ix1 = 0;
            outerLoop:
            while (ix1 < lines.size()) {
                // see if a repeating pattern starts at ix1
                for (int ix2 = ix1 + 1; ix2 < lines.size(); ix2++) {
                    if (lines.get(ix1).charAfterX == lines.get(ix2).charAfterX) {
                        int patternLength = ix2 - ix1;
                        int ix3 = ix2 + 1;
                        while (ix3 < lines.size() && lines.get(ix3).charAfterX == lines.get(ix3 - patternLength).charAfterX) {
                            ix3++;
                        }
                        int repeatedPatternLength = ix3 - ix1;
                        if (repeatedPatternLength > minRepeats  * patternLength) { // pattern found
                            int repeats = repeatedPatternLength / patternLength;
                            // a more elaborate solution may return the repeating pattern to the caller
                            System.out.println("Found a pattern repeated " + repeats + " times");
                            int repeatEndIndex = ix1 + repeats * patternLength;
                            for (int ix4 = ix1; ix4 < repeatEndIndex; ix4++) {
                                System.out.println(lines.get(ix4).line);
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                            ix1 = repeatEndIndex;
                            continue outerLoop;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // no repeating pattern found, try next index
                ix1++;
            }

            lines.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am sorry I did not get to reply to your comment regarding requirements. I was away. I will try your solution and add further comments.